# Passing parameters from component to another using Vue3 Composition API and vue-router .replace function

Tags: parameters, vuejs3, vue-router, vue-composition-api

With Option API I was able to do this:

In ComponentA:

```
this.$router.replace({ name: 'ComponentB', params:{data: myObject} });
```

In ComponentB:

```
console.log(this.$route.params); // this outputs myObject
```

With composition API this is what I did:

In ComponentA:

```
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router';
const router= useRouter();
router.replace({ name: 'ComponentB', params:{data: myObject}  });
```

In ComponentB:

```
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';
const route= useRoute();
console.log(route.params); // here i get empty object in the console {}
```

Clearly it's not working, but i can't find what i'm missing.

Answer (score 1):

In your router setup, make sure that you have defined 'ComponentB' with a parameter:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/componentA',
    name: 'ComponentA',
    component: ComponentA,
  },
  {
    path: '/componentB/:data',
    name: 'ComponentB',
    component: ComponentB,
  },
  //write your other routes here
];
export default router;
```

Comment: This works but you can't send objects directly, it only accepts primitive data types. In my case i need to send an object

Comment: You can serialize the object before sending it. In the receiving component you can deserialize it back.

Comment: Yeah that's what i ended up doing, but i just didn't like this method....